# Subdomains on Cloudflare and Heroku

Tags: heroku, subdomain, cloudflare

I have setup a cname for `mydomain.com` to be an alias of `app1.herokuapp.com` and it works. However, cname for `sub.mydomain.com` as an alias of `app2.herokuapp.com` does not work.

It does not work with either grey or orange cloud and having clicked on the "`I am done`" button.  Any ideas?

Comment: Im having the same problem - after enabling cloudflare it's directing to a different app!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get my domain/sub-domain mix to work over two Heroku apps. The key seems to be with Cloudflare and not Heroku.

I had things set as follows:-

```
CNAME www alias of app1.herokuapp.com (CloudFlare enabled)
CNAME mydomain.com alias of app1.herokuapp.com (CloudFlare enabled)
CNAME api alias of app2.herokuapp.com (No cloudflare)
```

Ensure the DNS records for your domain are set to the CloudFlare ones (`may.ns.cloudflare.com and sam.ns.cloudflare.com`) within CloudFlare and of course, set your Heroku DNS to pick up your domains.

Failing that, you should contact CloudFlare support, but unlike other answers here, the objective of SO is to provide an answer to a specific question first, to allow the OP to help themselves.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds likely to be a misconfiguration on Heroku's side, and less likely an issue on CloudFlare's side. Without being able to see your account specifics though it's hard to prove that conclusively.

Answer (score -6):

Can you please open up an actual CloudFlare support ticket with the specifics here? We'd be happy to look into this further, but we do need the specific settings/real and the domain/subdomain...etc.

https://support.cloudflare.com

Comment: This is utterly useless to anyone who comes by here looking for an answer!

Comment: @dooburt or, if you have an issue with a company you should actually contact their support directly instead of some 3rd party website. Just an idea.

Comment: and then the top answer on Google being this SO question, sends the user to this dead-end? Yeah, nice one.

Comment: @dooburt it's utterly useless to instead have a dead question because we can't look into the actual problem -- but yeah, good call ..don't write in to the actual support team.

Comment: why have you commented on this two years later? Read my answer, it says try something, if that fails contact support. The OP can then at least understand and solve the problem himself and visitors to this post can do the same. Just pointing people directly to support is completely against the point of SO. So do take you sarcasm elsewhere sir.